# How to import data by csv in bulk from files in one directory using Cypher in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

Hello I was tring to import data to Neo4j. I know that

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.1.3/csv/import/persons.csv" AS csvLine
CREATE (p:Person { id: toInt(csvLine.id), name: csvLine.name })
```

works for one file. But what if I have 800+ files in the same directory?

Comment: I tried a few different ways in REST/Cypher to do something better than repeating the LOAD CSV line 800+ times and had no success. I think you may have to use one of the programming APIs to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you would use a shell script that either posts these queries in turn to the server or executes a neo4j-shell with the statement.

```
for file in *.do; do
   bin/neo4j-shell -c "LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///users/abc/import/${file}' AS csvLine
CREATE (p:Person { id: toInt(csvLine.id), name: csvLine.name })"
done
```

Comment: Why is "bash: bin/neo4j-shell: No such file or directory"?

Comment: And kind of confused where should I put the dir name? Could you show that in the code if I want to load all csv files in file:///home/nate/Downloads/a directory(it only contains csv files)?

Comment: I instead combine those 800 files into one big csv file. It is 400MB and still running the query..